# How to use 'env' property in Nuxt.js to get newapi?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, nuxt.js, middleware

I try to make news web apps to use [newsapi.org.](https://newsapi.org/)
I wanted to hide my api_key so I decided to use env property in Nuxt.Js.
But now I got 401 status code from server.

first of all, I made the .env file in project file and I put my API_KEY.
and then I installed 'dotenv' use 'yarn add dotenv' command in VSCode terminal.

and I add nuxt.config.ts file. I have used TypeScript in my project so all file depend on TypeScript.

```
require('dotenv').config()
const { API_KEY } = process.env
export default {
 ~~~~~~~~~~
 env: {
    API_KEY,
  },
}
```

and I used Vuex to get news information.
so I made code like following.

~/store/getNews.ts

```
import { MutationTree, ActionTree, GetterTree } from "vuex";
import axios from "axios";
const url = 'http://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines';

interface RootState { }

export interface NewsArticles {
    source?: {}
    author?: string
    title?: string
    description?: string
    url?: any
    urlToImage?: any
    publishedAt?: string
    content?: string
}

interface State {
    newArticle: NewsArticles
}
export const state = () => ({
    newsArticle: []
})
export const getters: GetterTree<State, RootState> = {
    newsArticle: (state: State) => state.newArticle
}
export const mutations: MutationTree<State> = {
    setNewsArticle: (state: State, newsArticle: NewsArticles) => {
        state.newArticle = newsArticle
    }
}
export const actions: ActionTree<State, RootState> = {
    getNewsArticle: async ({ commit },{params}) => {
        try{
            const data = await axios.get(url,{params})
            commit('setNewsArticle', data.data.articles)
        }catch(error){
            commit('setNewsArticle',[])
        }
    }
}

export default { state, getters, mutations, actions }
```

and finally, I made vue file to show the news information like following.

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <p>this is NewsApi test pages!!</p>
    <ul v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="index">
      <li>{{ item.title }}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>
<script lang="ts">
import { Component, namespace, Vue } from 'nuxt-property-decorator'
import { NewsArticles } from '~/store/getNews'
const getNews = namespace('getNews')

@Component({})
export default class extends Vue {
  @getNews.Action getNewsArticle!: Function
  @getNews.Getter newsArticle!: NewsArticles
  items: any = []
  async mounted() {
    await this.getNewsArticle({
      params: { country: 'jp', category: 'business', apiKey: process.env.API_KEY },
    })
    this.items = this.newsArticle
  }
}
</script>
```

I ran my app but I got 401 status code and I checked the console error like following.

```
{status: "error", code: "apiKeyInvalid",…}
code: "apiKeyInvalid"
message: "Your API key is invalid or incorrect. Check your key, or go to https://newsapi.org to create a free API key."
status: "error"
```

I don't know why that error occurred.
I checked apikey correctly setting to confirm consle.log.

in index.vue

```html
<script lang='ts'>
~~~~
export default class extend Vue{
  mounted(){
   console.log(process.env.API_KEY)
}
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to call `require('dotenv').config()`, as Nuxt automatically invokes it.

Also, for the env vars to be available in the production build, their names must be [prefixed with `NUXT_ENV_`](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/configuration-glossary/configuration-env/#automatic-injection-of-environment-variables) (i.e., `NUXT_ENV_API_KEY`). Note this allows you to keep the key from being checked into source (assuming your `.env` file is also kept out of source control), but your API key can still be observed in the Network tab in DevTools.